# dask how to define a custom (time fold) function that operates in parallel and returns a dataframe with a different shape

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I am trying to implement a time fold function to be 'map'ed to various partitions of a dask dataframe which in turn changes the shape of the dataframe in question (or alternatively produces a new dataframe with the altered shape). This is how far I have gotten. The result 'res' returned on compute is a list of 3 delayed objects. When I try to compute each of them in a loop (last tow lines of code) this results in a **"TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable"** After going through the [examples for map_partitions](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.map_partitions), I also tried altering the input DF (inplace) in the function with no return value which causes a similar TypeError with NoneType. What am I missing?

Also, looking at the [visualization (attached)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I0Whd2exbXrU_pvOPMaroNV31_BI_sX9/view?usp=sharing) I feel like there is a need for reducing the individually computed (folded) partitions into a single DF. How do I do this?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

# Start dask scheduler and workers
# dask-scheduler &
# dask-worker --nthreads 1 --nprocs 6 --memory-limit 3GB localhost:8786 --local-directory /dev/shm &

from dask.distributed import Client
from dask.delayed import delayed
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dd
import math

foldbucketsecs=30
periodicitysecs=15
secsinday=24 * 60 * 60
chunksizesecs=60 # 1 minute
numts = 5
start = 1525132800 # 01/05
end = 1525132800 + (3 * 60) # 3 minute

c = Client('127.0.0.1:8786')

def fold(df, start, bucket):
    return df

def reduce_folds(df):
    return df

def load(epoch):
    idx = []
    for ts in range(0, chunksizesecs, periodicitysecs):
        idx.append(epoch + ts)
    d = np.random.rand(chunksizesecs/periodicitysecs, numts)
    ts = []
    for i in range(0, numts):
        tsname = "ts_%s" % (i)
        ts.append(tsname)
        gts.append(tsname)
    res = pd.DataFrame(index=idx, data=d, columns=ts, dtype=np.float64)
    res.index = pd.to_datetime(arg=res.index, unit='s')
    return res

gts = []
load(start)
cols = len(gts)

idx1 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start, freq=('%sS' % periodicitysecs), end=start+periodicitysecs, dtype='datetime64[s]')
meta = pd.DataFrame(index=idx1[:0], data=[], columns=gts, dtype=np.float64)
dfs = [delayed(load)(fn) for fn in range(start, end, chunksizesecs)]

from_delayed = dd.from_delayed(dfs, meta, 'sorted')

nfolds = int(math.ceil((end - start)/foldbucketsecs))
cprime = nfolds * cols

gtsnew = []

for i in range(0, cprime):
    gtsnew.append("ts_%s,fold=%s" % (i%cols, i/cols))

idx2 = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start, freq=('%sS' % periodicitysecs), end=start+foldbucketsecs, dtype='datetime64[s]')
meta = pd.DataFrame(index=idx2[:0], data=[], columns=gtsnew, dtype=np.float64)
folded_df = from_delayed.map_partitions(delayed(fold)(from_delayed, start, foldbucketsecs), meta=meta)
result = c.submit(reduce_folds, folded_df)

c.gather(result).visualize(filename='/usr/share/nginx/html/svg/df4.svg')

res = c.gather(result).compute()

for f in res:
    f.compute()
```

Comment: Can you produce a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I think it would be easier in order to receive help.

Comment: Hi @user32185, I have tidied up my main post and retained the fold function implementation. However, even over simplifying (scoop out everything but the return df at the end) the fold function also does not work. Throws the same TypeError.

Comment: Please do "scoop everything out", so that we are only left with the bare necessities to get to your exception

Comment: @mdurant. Can you please check now?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind! It was my fault, instead of wrapping my function in delayed I simply passed it to the map_partitions call like so and it worked.

`folded_df = from_delayed.map_partitions(fold, start, foldbucketsecs, nfolds, meta=meta)`